# ComboBox not filtering my JTable

Tags: java, combobox, jtable

I am using a ComboBox to filter out my JTable.
The JTable consists of Requirements, Type, Compliance column, and the ComboBox is used for the 'Type' header.

The JTable displays the data perfectly fine but when I select a type in the ComboBox none of the information is displayed, showing a blank table.

I'm posting below the class which extends JPanel and creates the JTable and has the logic of using the combobox, my defaulttablemodel, and my TableRowSorter

In main, i'm simply  making the jtable and jscrollpane visible

```
package view;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;

public class TempPanel extends JPanel {

    //Global Variables
    public JTable table;
    public JScrollPane js;
    DefaultTableModel dm;
    JButton btnDisplay;
    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    public TempPanel() {

        initialize();
        createColumns();


        //Manually adding to Jtable
        String rowReq[][] = {{"A", "1", null}, {"B", "2" ,null}, {"C", "2", null}};
        addData(rowReq[0][0], rowReq[0][1], rowReq[0][2]);
        addData(rowReq[1][0], rowReq[1][1], rowReq[1][2]);
        addData(rowReq[2][0], rowReq[2][1], rowReq[2][2]);

    }


    public void addData(String req, String type, String compliance) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String [] rowData = {req,type,compliance};
        dm.addRow(rowData);
    }

    //Filter my data
    private void filter(String query)
    {
        TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(dm);
        table.setRowSorter(tr);

        if ( query != "None")
        {
            tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(query));
        }
        else
        {
            table.setRowSorter(tr);
        }
    }


    private void createColumns() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Get table model

        dm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        dm.addColumn("Requirements");
        dm.addColumn("Type");
        dm.addColumn("Compliance");
    }



    public void initialize()
    {

        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
                String query = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                filter(query);
            }
        });
        comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Type1", "Type2", "Type3"}));
        comboBox.setBounds(30, 11, 64, 20);
        add(comboBox);

        table = new JTable(dm);
        table.setBounds(10, 42, 220, 127);

        js = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(js);

        btnDisplay = new JButton("Display");
        btnDisplay.setBounds(307, 10, 89, 23);
        add(btnDisplay);

        js.setVisible(false);
        table.setVisible(false);

        //Manually adding data to jtable

    }
}
```

Comment: `regexFilter` method is supposed to accept an array of column indices. If you don't give it any, it uses all columns - and I guess your "Requirements" or "Compliance" columns don't contain values that would match your types.

Comment: Also, you probably don't really want the `regexFilter` in the first place - just use base equality filter, it would be much simpler and faster. Extend `RowFilter` class and implement `include` method properly.

Comment: All my columns are strings, and it doesn't matter if the regexFilter is using all columns since my comboBox only contains 'Type1' 'Type2' 'Type3'

Comment: Should I really be extending RowFilter class on a class that already extends JPanel?

Comment: Why are you concerned with extending classes? You can't directly use `RowFilter` (unless I'm missing something really obvious), you have to extend it. Regex evaluation adds unnecessary overhead to filtering that is essentially a comparison of two arrays with no fancy logic to it. Also, by extending it you can debug it better and see what actually happens.

Comment: Having trouble understanding how it should be done, could you please be more specific? Or provide a suggested solution